# Distribution of $\int_{t}^{T} W(s)ds$ where $W$ is Brownian motion

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution, brownian-motion

> What is the distribution of $\int_{t}^{T} W(s)ds$ given that $W$ is a Brownian motion?

So far, I have the following,
$$\int_{t}^{T} W(s)ds = (T-t)W(t) + \int_{t}^{T} (T-s)dW(s)$$
Also, $$\int_{0}^{T} (T-s)dW(s) \sim N(0,\frac{T^{3}}{3})$$

Answer (score 1):

By definition $X=\displaystyle\int_t^TW(s)\mathrm ds$ is Gaussian. Every $W(s)$ is centered hence $X$ is centered. To complete the characterization of the distribution of $X$, it suffices to compute its variance, which is
$$
E[X^2]=\int_t^T\int_t^TE[W(s)W(r)]\mathrm dr\mathrm ds=\int_t^T\int_t^T\text{______}=\text{___}.$$

Comment: Why is the fact $X=\int Wds$ is Gaussian *by definition*? I know one can discretise it into Riemannian sum which after splitting $W$ into tiny independent increments is just a linear sum of independent normal distributions, but I don't think this thread of logic is "trivial" at first glance.

Comment: @Vim Anyway, it is Gaussian.

Comment: ok. I'm just wondering what "definition" do you mean here.